# spring webclient: retry with backoff on specific error

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

i'd like to retry the request 3 times after waiting 10sec when response is 5xx. but i don't see a method that I can use. On object

```
WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("...").build().post()
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(...)
```

i can see methods:

retrying on condition with retry count but no delay

```
.retry(3, {it is WebClientResponseException && it.statusCode.is5xxServerError} )
```

retrying with backoff and number of times but no condition

```
.retryBackoff
```

there is also a `retryWhen` but i'm not sure how to use it

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With reactor-extra you could do it like:

```
.retryWhen(Retry.onlyIf(this::is5xxServerError)
        .fixedBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .retryMax(3))

private boolean is5xxServerError(RetryContext<Object> retryContext) {
    return retryContext.exception() instanceof WebClientResponseException &&
            ((WebClientResponseException) retryContext.exception()).getStatusCode().is5xxServerError();
}
```

**Update:**
With new API the same solution will be:

```
    .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .filter(this::is5xxServerError));

//...

private boolean is5xxServerError(Throwable throwable) {
    return throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException &&
            ((WebClientResponseException) throwable).getStatusCode().is5xxServerError();
}
```

Comment: @RobertW. , I've never used coroutines before. I'll try to investigate your problem this weekend.

Comment: fixed it, will answer my own question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60827183/spring-webclient-retry-with-webflux-fn-reactor-addons

Comment: this is deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this taking the following approach:

- Use the `exchange()` method to obtain the response without an exception, and then throw a specific (custom) exception on a 5xx response (this differs from `retrieve()` which will always throw `WebClientResponseException` with either a `4xx` or `5xx` status);
- Intercept this specific exception in your retry logic;
- Use [`reactor-extra`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor.addons/reactor-extra) - it contains a nice way to use `retryWhen()` for more complex & specific retries. You can then specify a random backoff retry that starts after 10 seconds, goes up to an arbitrary time and tries a maximum of 3 times. (Or you can use the [other available methods](https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/retry/Retry.html) to pick a different strategy of course.)

For example:

```
//...webclient
.exchange()
.flatMap(clientResponse -> {
    if (clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
        return Mono.error(new ServerErrorException());
    } else {
        //Any further processing
    }
}).retryWhen(
    Retry.anyOf(ServerErrorException.class)
       .randomBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(10), Duration.ofHours(1))
       .maxRetries(3)
    )
);
```

Comment: Inside the `retryWhen()` can we use different Retry policies for different  Exception ? Let's say for some exception we'd like  a higer `maxRetries` for example ?

Comment: `retryWhen(reactor.retry.Retry)` method is deprecated and to be removed in v3.4. But use `retryWhen(reactor.util.retry.Retry)`

Answer (score 8):

the retryWhen with Retry.anyOf and Retry.onlyIf are deprecated I assume. I found this approach useful, and it allows us to process and throw a User defined exception.

for example :

```
retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.of(2, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                        .filter(error -> error instanceof UserDefinedException/AnyOtherException)
                        .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) ->
                                new UserDefinedException(retrySignal.failure().getMessage())))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// ...
.retryWhen(
    backoff(maxAttempts, minBackoff)
        .filter(throwable -> ((WebClientResponseException) throwable).getStatusCode().is5xxServerError()))
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding only withThrowable to your existing code can make it work. This has worked for me. You can try something like this :

For example :

```
.retryWhen(withThrowable(Retry.any()
    .doOnRetry(e -> log
        .debug("Retrying to data for {} due to exception: {}", employeeId, e.exception().getMessage()))
    .retryMax(config.getServices().getRetryAttempts())
    .backoff(Backoff.fixed(Duration.ofSeconds(config.getServices().getRetryBackoffSeconds())))))
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how i do it:

```
 .retryWhen(retryBackoffSpec())

private RetryBackoffSpec retryBackoffSpec() {
        return Retry.backoff(RETRY_ATTEMPTS, Duration.ofSeconds(RETRY_DELAY))
                .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof yourException);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `reactor.retry.Retry` from `reactor-extra` is deprecated and should be avoided. Use the `reactor.util.Retry` class from `reactor-core`.

There is a convenient way to map response statuses to concrete exceptions using the `onStatus` method.

So, if you want to retry on 5xx status codes, a simple solution would be to throw a `CustomException` on 5xx and retry only when exception is `CustomException`.

```
// Retry only on 5xx
webClient.post()
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::is5xxClientError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new CustomException()))
    .bodyToMono(...)
    .retryWhen(Retry.max(3).filter(t -> t instanceof CustomException))

// Alternatively if you don't want to fail/retry on certain status code you can also return an empty `Mono` to ignore the error and propagate the response
webClient.post()
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(httpStatusCode -> httpStatusCode.value() == 404, clientResponse -> Mono.empty())
    .bodyToMono(...)
    .retryWhen(Retry.max(3).filter(t -> t instanceof CustomException))
```