# Looking for an alternative of retryWhen which is now Deprecated

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I'm facing an issue with `WebClient` and `reactor-extra`. Indeed, I have the following method :

```
public Employee getEmployee(String employeeId) {
            return webClient.get()
                    .uri(FIND_EMPLOYEE_BY_ID_URL, employeeId)
                    .retrieve()
                    .onStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND::equals, clientResponse -> Mono.empty())
                    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new MyCustomException("Something went wrong calling getEmployeeById")))
                    .bodyToMono(Employee.class)
                    .retryWhen(Retry.onlyIf(ConnectTimeoutException.class)
                             .fixedBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                             .retryMax(3))
                    .block();
    }
```

I've found that I could use `retryWhen(Retry.onlyIf(...))` because I want to retry only if a `ConnectTimeoutException` is thrown. I've found this solution from this post : [spring webclient: retry with backoff on specific error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58520919/spring-webclient-retry-with-backoff-on-specific-error)

But, in the latest version of `reactor` the following method became deprecated :

`public final Mono<T> retryWhen(Function<Flux<Throwable>, ? extends Publisher<?>> whenFactory)`

After hours of googling I haven't found any solution to this question : Is there any alternative for `retryWhen` and `Retry.onlyIf` with the latest versions of `reactor`

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Retry used to essentially be a utility function generator distributed as part of `reactor-extra`. The API has been altered a bit now and brought into `reactor-core` (`reactor.util.retry.Retry`), with the old `retryWhen()` variant deprecated. So no need to include extra anymore - in your case, you can do something like:

```
.retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .filter(e -> e instanceof ConnectTimeoutException))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is excatly what I looked for :) And thanks for the explanation:D

Comment: cant find Retry.fixedDelay in reactor-extra 3.4.1...

Comment: @user1955934 As in the answer - the class you need is now in `reactor-core`, not `reactor-extra`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding only withThrowable to your existing code can make it work. This has worked for me. You can try something like this :

For example :

```
.retryWhen(withThrowable(Retry.any()
        .doOnRetry(e -> log
            .debug("Retrying to data for {} due to exception: {}", employeeId, e.exception().getMessage()))
        .retryMax(config.getServices().getRetryAttempts())
        .backoff(Backoff.fixed(Duration.ofSeconds(config.getServices().getRetryBackoffSeconds())))))
```