# putting retry policy on reactive webclient

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webclient, retrywhen

I am new to reactive programming.
we have a spring boot application, in which we make sync and async calls.
Now I want to put a common retry policy in those calls.

We have only 1 place where we create webclient object, and then use it across the code.

I want to put retry logic on this webclient so that I dont have to change all method calls.

But I dont find any api to put retry policy on webclient. all I could see is when we retrieve response, but in this case, I would have to go and modify at each call. Eg :
[image]
Is there any way where I can make changes to webclient to have a default retry policy.

Comment: looks like there is no default place but you can use the api like https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521980/175554